# How do I map a drive letter to a network share for all RDP users on a Windows Server 2016

Tags: windows-server-2016, mappeddrive

I want to map a new drive letter F: for all users that login to my application server on Azure so they can edit files that are on a separate network share \FileServer\StorageDrive. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I simply placed the following commands in a new text file called C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\StartUp\MAPDRIVES.BAT:

```
net use F: /delete
net use F: \\FileServer\StorageDrive
```

When I had everyone log off and log back in, the new drive letter F: appeared for each user.

Answer (score 0):

If you've got Active Directory available, you can use a Group Policy Preferences GPO item to add the Mapped Drive. Also you can set a logon script (I usually store it in //domain/netlogon) on the user's profile to do the `net use` commands.